# How to get date data every ten minutes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript

Do you know a good way to generate date data that advances each 10 minutes and put an array?

```
let dts:Dates = new array();

let dt: Date = new Date('2019-05-03T06:00:00');
let dt2: Date = new Date('2019-05-03T06:00:00');
let dt3: Date = new Date('2019-05-03T06:00:00');

dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 10);
console.log(dt);
dt2.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 10);
console.log(dt2);
dt3.setMinutes(dt2.getMinutes() + 10);
console.log(dt3);


while(dt.getTime()<= 6 ){ // I would like from 6:00 , 6:20 ... (7:00) Is it impossible to add 7:00?
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 10);
console.log(dt);
}
```

Comment: are you looking for setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var origDateObj = new Date();
    var updatedDateObj = new Date();

    //The 10 in the line below will determine the amount of time added.
    updatedDateObj.setTime(origDateObj.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));

    console.log(updatedDateObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. The trick is to do this in a loop, and to create a new instance of Date in each iteration of the loop:

```js
const startDate = new Date('2019-05-03T06:00:00');
const numberOfItems = 12;

const dates = Array.from({ length: numberOfItems }, (_, i) => {
  const nextDate = new Date(startDate);
  nextDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + i * 10);
  return nextDate;
});

console.log(dates.map(String));
```

You may of course want to wrap this in a function to suit your needs:

```js
function dateIncrements(startDate, incrementMinutes, numberOfItems) {
  return Array.from({ length: numberOfItems }, (_, i) => {
    const nextDate = new Date(startDate);
    nextDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + i * incrementMinutes);
    return nextDate;
  });
}

const dates = dateIncrements(new Date('2019-05-03T06:00:00'), 10, 6);
console.log(dates.map(String));
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)? It seems to me you could make it cleaner by using a native method...